# C# class validate and correct using data attributes

Tags: c#, validation

I'm trying to validate a class against its attributes like required, max length, default value and such. I don't want to just determine if the object is valid or not, I also want to try to correct the values by means of trimming, initializing ( null to "" if a required field is left empty , for instance)

I did found some posts that talk about manual validation of a class.

http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2011/06/29/manual-validation-with-data-annotations.aspx

http://aboutdev.wordpress.com/2009/12/20/poor-mans-validation/

But not sure how do I correct the object values of they're invalid.

Again this is a simple POCO class, and my only concern is to validate the class, if what I'm trying to accomplish is not possible I can always manually validate each property. Suggestions welcomed.

Currently I'm trying to accomplish this using indexer and Validator.TryValidateObject() as follows :

```
class Customer
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "required"), MaxLength(250)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue('N')]
    public char Active { get; set; }

    public object this[string propertyName]
    {
        get { return this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(this, null); }
        set { this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(this, value, null); }
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var customer = new Customer { Id = 1, Active = 'Y', Name = null };

        var context = new ValidationContext(customer, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        bool isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(customer, context, results); // false
        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            object value = customer[result.MemberNames.First().ToString()];
            switch (result.ErrorMessage)
            {
                case "required" :
                    customer[result.MemberNames.First().ToString()] = "John Smith";
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        results.Clear();
        isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(customer, context, results); // true
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't usually correct the values (after all how do you know what they should be), you simply display an approprite message in the UI telling the user why the values are invalid.

Comment: @BenRobinson, agreed. But here I am trying to pass the data to an internal web-service, and I've received the validation specifications from the team. My goal was to add attributes to the model class ( or 'Contract' as I call) and somehow to come up with the validation/correction scenario.

Comment: @ablaze It is difficult to give specific advice without the details of the system but broadly if its interactive show an appropriate error to the user, if its automated log the errors.

Comment: If you paste your code it's easier for us to help you modify it accordingly rather than asking the community to provide a full-fledged example from scratch.

Comment: If a required field is left empty, it would be a bad idea for a validation layer to fill it anyway, because the upper layer will have no idea what's going wrong anymore. It's very unlikely that "fixing" the values will end up with a request that does what we want -- and that's the goal, not to get a request that's merely valid. Suppose you helpfully "trim" a user name field that's too long? Bam, potential security issue. If you must do this, be sure to separate it from validation.

Comment: @atornblad, & Chris Searles : I've added the code snippet.

Comment: @BenRobinson, this is not an interactive GUI application, this is a WCF service. Personally, I too shared same opinion as yours but this is what business logic side needs to be implemented, and sadly I can not change it :-/

Comment: @ablaze The code you have posted is not for a WCF service. If you are using a WCF service then the service should return a validation error message to the user if the data is not valid. If somebody is telling you to "correct" the validation errors educate them on why it is not going to work.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, thanks for the advice, and you're damn right ! But I can not change it :/

Comment: so far the only way around I see is to log it

Comment: @BenRobinson: I could do that. Here is the thing, this a WCF application using Plugin Architecture ( using MEF ) and what I am asking applies to only one of the plugins. And the WCF application gets feeds from MSMQ using Fire-And-Forget pattern. In principle what they're putting to the queue is already valid from their point. The teams of these projects had a discussion and they came up with this idea, all I can do is to assume that it won't have any issues including those Jeroen mentioned. [:shrug:] ... and the code you're seeing is a demo code I wrote to share.